# Every integral domain can be embedded in a field. Can this be generalized?

Tags: ring-theory

Every integral domain can be embedded in a field. I'm wondering if this result can be generalized.

My question is, "Can every commutative unital ring $R$ be embedded in another ring $S$ such that the elements of $R$ with the [cancellation property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_property) are precisely those that are mapped to [units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_%28ring_theory%29) of $S$?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [total quotient ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_quotient_ring) inverts every non-zero-divisor. It is a special case of a [localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring), which inverts all elements from an arbitrary (saturated) submonoid of the multiplicative group.